# Day Change Update Problem

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, algorithm, methodology

**C#  -  Winforms  -  SQL Server**

i am building an application which displays some data on the screen of the current day which it gets from the database... the application is like a desktop widget so the data  is always visible on the desktop

the **scheme** i implemented is

when user commits some change to the data, after the update query i call the "update display" function... and the new data is retrieved...

by doing so i don't have too check constantly/periodically for changes in the database and data on the display is always current.. this sort of becomes **PUSH** technology

now it keeps track of the data in the database for every day but only today's data is displayed... and when the program starts (manually\system start-up), it checks the date and

- if the record of the current day doesn't exist, it creates it and start display which can be later modified
- if the record exists then it just simply start display and there are interfaces available for modifying data

now the problem is

**If the PC is running & Application is running at 12:00 pm and the date changes... There is no technique to check that :**

- the day has changed and new record has to be created in database and the display needs to be refreshed

now i can continuously check via loop for the date change and solve my problem but i would love if there is a better option...

Comment: p.s. not exactly PUSH but sort of... plz don't comment about PUSH thingy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a Timer upon program startup to notify you when midnight happens.  i.e. If the program starts up at 8AM then set a timer to fire at midnight.

Link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(VS.71).aspx

Comment: you mean calculate time between now and midnight lets say T... set the timer interval to T and within T have the desired code and after desired code T set up timer interval for 24 hours and launch time again...

Comment: And if you think of it as a "refresh" timer, as opposed to a "date changed" timer, you could attach a number of events to it as required (including date changed).

Answer (score 1):

You could add a timer control to the form and set the interval to 86400000 ms - calculating the initial value on first startup.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on unix/linux you can run a cron job that kicks off an event. If you are on windows, set the task-scheduler to kick off an event.

And that event might be running a small app/script, stored procedure, etc., to do what you want.

Comment: i like this as well... by the way i like much better than the timer.. but the thing is it has manually scheduled... it won't be a part of the a=solution

Answer (score -2):

Use a [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) to check for the current date every second. Every time it changes, you can create your new record in the database.

Comment: having a timer checking everysecond isn't very different from a loop